# How to disable HTML validation in React using formsy-react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, validation

I'm trying to get rid of the browser's default validation logic using formsy-react, and according to the documentation the "[formNoValidation](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/blob/master/API.md#formnovalidate)" attribute should do the trick. But I can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var React = require('React');
var Formsy = require('formsy-react');
var Input = require('./forms/Input.js');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
           <Formsy.Form>
              <Input ref="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" value={this.state.phonenumber.value} name="phonenumber" required validations="isNumeric" validationError="Please provide a valid phone number" />
           </Formsy.Form>
        );
    }
});
```

Input.js

```
var Formsy = require('formsy-react');
var React = require('React');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Formsy.Mixin],
    
    changeValue: function (event) {
        this.setValue(event.currentTarget.value);
    },
    
    render: function () {
        var className = this.showRequired() ? 'required' : this.showError() ? 'error' : null;
        var isReadOnly = this.props.readOnly;
        var errorMessage = this.getErrorMessage();
        
        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.changeValue} value={this.getValue()} readOnly={isReadOnly} required={this.isRequired()} formNoValidate />
                <span>{errorMessage}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

[image: Default validation message, even though the formnovalidate attribute is present]

Comment: In your example, you show a form with a single Input element. However, in your screenshot, it looks like you are rendering other elements in your form. Where there is a single element, it becomes the default control that submits the form, so formNoValidate works. https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/issues/89#issuecomment-104954263

Comment: The code examples are just stripped down. I have several input elements.

Comment: The `formNoValidate` attribute is intended for elements that submit the form. Placing it on a "texty" type of input will only work if it is the only input in the form, as it becomes the input that submits the form.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `formNoValidate` attribute is only intended for elements that submit the form. So, placing it on a "text" type of input will work if it is the only input in the form (no submit button).

Imagine having a form for writing an article, It could have two submit buttons, one for "Save draft" that doesn't need to run native validation, and one for "Publish" that does.

Adding `noValidate` on the form tag should disable native validation on the form completely, however this isn't possible until issue [issue 89](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/issues/89) is resolved (scheduled for the next release).

Answer (score 3):

write "novalidate" in form tag.

Example

```
    <form method="post" novalidate>...</form>
```

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_form_novalidate)

Comment: Unfortunately, "Formsy.Form" doesn't seem to handle that.

Answer (score 3):

To disable HTML validation, use noValidate, it`s camel case sensitve:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate>

// code

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, [this is a way](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/issues/89) around the problem:

```
<Formsy.Form>
   <Input ref="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" validations="isNumeric" validationError="Oppgi et gyldig telefonnummer"/>
   <input type="submit" formNoValidate value="Submit"/>
</Formsy.Form>
```